# Force Haswell driver installation on Zenbook

Tags: windows-8, drivers, haswell

Latest VGA driver on Asus support page for Zenbook UX302 is 10.18.10.3325, but on Intel, for HD 4400 is 10.18.10.3621 (battery life on this zenbook is really short, so I'm hoping to get more with newer drivers). When I download them from Intel, it refuses to install, it says I have to use manufacturers drivers. And Asus just don't care about updating them, it seems to me.
Is there any way of "tricking" original Intel drivers to force them skip this check?

Comment: You can download the `.zip` package, extract it somewhere, and then try to [manually update the driver](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9695-driver-install-device-manager-windows-8-a.html). Keep in mind the drivers provided by Intel are *generic* ones, and they might not be fully compatible with your hardware, if at all. Your actual problem is battery life, which depends on multiple factors. If you haven't already, you should look at the whole picture in order to determine possible issue and solutions. For what is worth, I don't think a slightly newer driver would have a relevant impact.

Comment: good idea with unpacking and manual installation! I'll create restore point and try it. And yes, I doubt it will affect battery life, but just wanted to try.

Comment: @and31415 thanks, it's working! Post this as regular answer and I'll accept it as an correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

To get latest display drivers even Intel HD GPU installation drivers refuses to install, you need first uninstall all Intel GPU drivers of Windows. Especially check Device Manager, and make sure there's Microsoft Generic driver. Only then Intel drivers will install correctly!